# Xamarin Visual Studio doesnt generate Resource Designer because of AndroidBinded Library

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.android

Xamarin Visual Studio doesnt generate Resource Designer because of AndroidBinded Library

I currently cannot create new shape drawable or images and reference them in xml. I tried to bind the library MPAndroidChart with RoundBarchart and I used it successfully but It seems there was a price to pay.

This the AAR Project [Forked-MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/montecillodavidacn/MPAndroidChart)

And this is the Xamarin.Android Binded Library [Forked-repo Of MPAndroidChart.Xamarin](https://github.com/montecillodavidacn/MPAndroidChart.Xamarin)

This is the build output of the solution android binded library(MPAndroidChart.Xamarin):

```
>------ Rebuild All started: Project: MPAndroidChart, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>JARTOXML : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning : ignoring option UseSplitVerifier; support was removed in 8.0
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8A04: <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.github.mikephil']"/> matched no nodes.
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8A04: <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.github.mikephil.charting.interfaces']"/> matched no nodes.
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8A00: <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.github.mikephil.charting.interfaces.datasets']/interface[@name='IDataSet']/method[@name='getEntryForXIndex' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='int']]"/> matched no nodes.
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8A00: <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.github.mikephil.charting.interfaces.datasets']/interface[@name='IDataSet']/method[@name='getEntryForXIndex' and count(parameter)=2 and parameter[1][@type='int'] and parameter[2][@type='com.github.mikephil.charting.data.DataSet.Rounding']]"/> matched no nodes.
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8A00: <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.github.mikephil.charting.interfaces.datasets']/interface[@name='IDataSet']/method[@name='getEntryForXPos' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='float']]"/> matched no nodes.
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8A00: <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.github.mikephil.charting.interfaces.datasets']/interface[@name='IDataSet']/method[@name='getEntryForXPos' and count(parameter)=2 and parameter[1][@type='float'] and parameter[2][@type='com.github.mikephil.charting.data.DataSet.Rounding']]"/> matched no nodes.
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8800: Unknown parameter type System.Xml.XmlReader in method CreateFromXml in managed type Android.Content.Res.ColorStateList.
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8800: Unknown parameter type System.Xml.XmlReader in method ParseBundleExtras in managed type Android.Content.Res.Resources.
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8800: Unknown parameter type System.Xml.XmlReader in method CreateFromXml in managed type Android.Graphics.Drawables.Drawable.
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8800: Unknown parameter type System.Xml.XmlReader in method CreateFromXmlInner in managed type Android.Graphics.Drawables.Drawable.
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8800: Unknown parameter type System.Xml.XmlReader in method Inflate in managed type Android.Graphics.Drawables.Drawable.
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8800: Unknown parameter type System.Xml.XmlReader in method ParseIntent in managed type Android.Content.Intent.
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8800: Unknown parameter type System.Xml.XmlReader in method ReadFromXml in managed type Android.Content.IntentFilter.
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8900: Type com.github.mikephil.charting.highlight.Highlight: FxDG naming violation: Type name 'Highlight' matches namespace part 'Highlight'.
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8900: Type com.github.mikephil.charting.renderer.Renderer: FxDG naming violation: Type name 'Renderer' matches namespace part 'Renderer'.
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8401: Skipping MikePhil.Charting.Jobs.AnimatedViewPortJob.Phase, due to a duplicate field, method or nested type name.
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8401: Skipping MikePhil.Charting.Jobs.AnimatedViewPortJob.XOrigin, due to a duplicate field, method or nested type name.
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8401: Skipping MikePhil.Charting.Jobs.AnimatedViewPortJob.YOrigin, due to a duplicate field, method or nested type name.
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8401: Skipping MikePhil.Charting.Jobs.ViewPortJob.XValue, due to a duplicate field, method or nested type name.
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8401: Skipping MikePhil.Charting.Jobs.ViewPortJob.YValue, due to a duplicate field, method or nested type name.
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8401: Skipping MikePhil.Charting.Matrix.Vector3.Zero, due to a duplicate field, method or nested type name.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.BuildConfig.cs(35,30,35,47): warning CS0109: The member 'BuildConfig.java_class_handle' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.BuildConfig.cs(36,30,36,39): warning CS0109: The member 'BuildConfig.class_ref' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Buffer.AbstractBuffer.cs(134,30,134,47): warning CS0109: The member 'AbstractBuffer.java_class_handle' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Buffer.AbstractBuffer.cs(135,30,135,39): warning CS0109: The member 'AbstractBuffer.class_ref' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Util.ObjectPool.cs(128,30,128,47): warning CS0109: The member 'ObjectPool.java_class_handle' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Util.ObjectPool.cs(129,30,129,39): warning CS0109: The member 'ObjectPool.class_ref' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Util.ObjectPool.cs(36,31,36,48): warning CS0109: The member 'ObjectPool.Poolable.java_class_handle' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Util.ObjectPool.cs(37,31,37,40): warning CS0109: The member 'ObjectPool.Poolable.class_ref' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Util.Transformer.cs(191,30,191,47): warning CS0109: The member 'Transformer.java_class_handle' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Util.Transformer.cs(192,30,192,39): warning CS0109: The member 'Transformer.class_ref' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Util.Utils.cs(43,30,43,47): warning CS0109: The member 'Utils.java_class_handle' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Util.Utils.cs(44,30,44,39): warning CS0109: The member 'Utils.class_ref' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Util.ViewPortHandler.cs(164,30,164,47): warning CS0109: The member 'ViewPortHandler.java_class_handle' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Util.ViewPortHandler.cs(165,30,165,39): warning CS0109: The member 'ViewPortHandler.class_ref' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Util.EntryXComparator.cs(11,30,11,47): warning CS0109: The member 'EntryXComparator.java_class_handle' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Util.EntryXComparator.cs(12,30,12,39): warning CS0109: The member 'EntryXComparator.class_ref' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Highlight.ChartHighlighter.cs(58,30,58,47): warning CS0109: The member 'ChartHighlighter.java_class_handle' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Highlight.ChartHighlighter.cs(59,30,59,39): warning CS0109: The member 'ChartHighlighter.class_ref' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Util.ColorTemplate.cs(91,30,91,47): warning CS0109: The member 'ColorTemplate.java_class_handle' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Util.ColorTemplate.cs(92,30,92,39): warning CS0109: The member 'ColorTemplate.class_ref' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Util.FileUtils.cs(11,30,11,47): warning CS0109: The member 'FileUtils.java_class_handle' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Util.FileUtils.cs(12,30,12,39): warning CS0109: The member 'FileUtils.class_ref' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Highlight.Highlight.cs(11,30,11,47): warning CS0109: The member 'Highlight.java_class_handle' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Highlight.Highlight.cs(12,30,12,39): warning CS0109: The member 'Highlight.class_ref' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Highlight.PieRadarHighlighter.cs(58,30,58,47): warning CS0109: The member 'PieRadarHighlighter.java_class_handle' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Highlight.PieRadarHighlighter.cs(59,30,59,39): warning CS0109: The member 'PieRadarHighlighter.class_ref' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Data.BarEntry.cs(16,55,16,62): warning CS0108: 'BarEntry.Creator' hides inherited member 'Entry.Creator'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Highlight.Range.cs(64,30,64,47): warning CS0109: The member 'Range.java_class_handle' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Highlight.Range.cs(65,30,65,39): warning CS0109: The member 'Range.class_ref' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Data.BaseDataSet.cs(250,30,250,47): warning CS0109: The member 'BaseDataSet.java_class_handle' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Data.BaseDataSet.cs(251,30,251,39): warning CS0109: The member 'BaseDataSet.class_ref' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Data.BaseEntry.cs(11,30,11,47): warning CS0109: The member 'BaseEntry.java_class_handle' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Data.BaseEntry.cs(12,30,12,39): warning CS0109: The member 'BaseEntry.class_ref' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Animation.ChartAnimator.cs(51,30,51,47): warning CS0109: The member 'ChartAnimator.java_class_handle' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Animation.ChartAnimator.cs(52,30,52,39): warning CS0109: The member 'ChartAnimator.class_ref' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Animation.Easing.cs(816,30,816,47): warning CS0109: The member 'Easing.java_class_handle' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Animation.Easing.cs(817,30,817,39): warning CS0109: The member 'Easing.class_ref' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Listener.ChartTouchListener.cs(336,30,336,47): warning CS0109: The member 'ChartTouchListener.java_class_handle' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Listener.ChartTouchListener.cs(337,30,337,39): warning CS0109: The member 'ChartTouchListener.class_ref' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Animation.Easing.cs(379,31,379,48): warning CS0109: The member 'Easing.EasingFunctions.java_class_handle' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Animation.Easing.cs(380,31,380,40): warning CS0109: The member 'Easing.EasingFunctions.class_ref' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Listener.ChartTouchListener.cs(286,31,286,48): warning CS0109: The member 'ChartTouchListener.ChartGesture.java_class_handle' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Listener.ChartTouchListener.cs(287,31,287,40): warning CS0109: The member 'ChartTouchListener.ChartGesture.class_ref' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Animation.Easing.cs(766,31,766,48): warning CS0109: The member 'Easing.EasingOption.java_class_handle' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Animation.Easing.cs(767,31,767,40): warning CS0109: The member 'Easing.EasingOption.class_ref' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Charts.Chart.cs(530,30,530,47): warning CS0109: The member 'Chart.java_class_handle' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Charts.Chart.cs(531,30,531,39): warning CS0109: The member 'Chart.class_ref' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Animation.IEasingFunction.cs(13,9,13,25): warning CS0108: 'IEasingFunction.GetInterpolation(float)' hides inherited member 'ITimeInterpolator.GetInterpolation(float)'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Exception.DrawingDataSetNotCreatedException.cs(11,30,11,47): warning CS0109: The member 'DrawingDataSetNotCreatedException.java_class_handle' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Exception.DrawingDataSetNotCreatedException.cs(12,30,12,39): warning CS0109: The member 'DrawingDataSetNotCreatedException.class_ref' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Listener.OnDrawLineChartTouchListener.cs(11,30,11,47): warning CS0109: The member 'OnDrawLineChartTouchListener.java_class_handle' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Listener.OnDrawLineChartTouchListener.cs(12,30,12,39): warning CS0109: The member 'OnDrawLineChartTouchListener.class_ref' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Formatter.DefaultAxisValueFormatter.cs(54,30,54,47): warning CS0109: The member 'DefaultAxisValueFormatter.java_class_handle' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Formatter.DefaultAxisValueFormatter.cs(55,30,55,39): warning CS0109: The member 'DefaultAxisValueFormatter.class_ref' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Formatter.DefaultFillFormatter.cs(11,30,11,47): warning CS0109: The member 'DefaultFillFormatter.java_class_handle' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Formatter.DefaultFillFormatter.cs(12,30,12,39): warning CS0109: The member 'DefaultFillFormatter.class_ref' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Formatter.DefaultValueFormatter.cs(54,30,54,47): warning CS0109: The member 'DefaultValueFormatter.java_class_handle' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Formatter.DefaultValueFormatter.cs(55,30,55,39): warning CS0109: The member 'DefaultValueFormatter.class_ref' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Listener.PieRadarChartTouchListener.cs(55,31,55,48): warning CS0109: The member 'PieRadarChartTouchListener.AngularVelocitySample.java_class_handle' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Listener.PieRadarChartTouchListener.cs(56,31,56,40): warning CS0109: The member 'PieRadarChartTouchListener.AngularVelocitySample.class_ref' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Matrix.Vector3.cs(110,30,110,47): warning CS0109: The member 'Vector3.java_class_handle' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Matrix.Vector3.cs(111,30,111,39): warning CS0109: The member 'Vector3.class_ref' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Formatter.IndexAxisValueFormatter.cs(11,30,11,47): warning CS0109: The member 'IndexAxisValueFormatter.java_class_handle' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Formatter.IndexAxisValueFormatter.cs(12,30,12,39): warning CS0109: The member 'IndexAxisValueFormatter.class_ref' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Formatter.LargeValueFormatter.cs(11,30,11,47): warning CS0109: The member 'LargeValueFormatter.java_class_handle' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Formatter.LargeValueFormatter.cs(12,30,12,39): warning CS0109: The member 'LargeValueFormatter.class_ref' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Formatter.PercentFormatter.cs(34,30,34,47): warning CS0109: The member 'PercentFormatter.java_class_handle' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Formatter.PercentFormatter.cs(35,30,35,39): warning CS0109: The member 'PercentFormatter.class_ref' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Formatter.StackedValueFormatter.cs(11,30,11,47): warning CS0109: The member 'StackedValueFormatter.java_class_handle' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Formatter.StackedValueFormatter.cs(12,30,12,39): warning CS0109: The member 'StackedValueFormatter.class_ref' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Renderer.BarLineScatterCandleBubbleRenderer.cs(98,31,98,48): warning CS0109: The member 'BarLineScatterCandleBubbleRenderer.XBounds.java_class_handle' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Renderer.BarLineScatterCandleBubbleRenderer.cs(99,31,99,40): warning CS0109: The member 'BarLineScatterCandleBubbleRenderer.XBounds.class_ref' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Charts.CombinedChart.cs(122,31,122,48): warning CS0109: The member 'CombinedChart.DrawOrder.java_class_handle' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Charts.CombinedChart.cs(123,31,123,40): warning CS0109: The member 'CombinedChart.DrawOrder.class_ref' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Charts.HorizontalBarChart.cs(16,26,16,44): warning CS0108: 'HorizontalBarChart.MGetPositionBuffer' hides inherited member 'BarLineChartBase.MGetPositionBuffer'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Data.ChartData.cs(195,30,195,47): warning CS0109: The member 'ChartData.java_class_handle' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Data.ChartData.cs(196,30,196,39): warning CS0109: The member 'ChartData.class_ref' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Data.CombinedData.cs(279,30,279,40): warning CS0114: 'CombinedData.CalcMinMax()' hides inherited member 'ChartData.CalcMinMax()'. To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword. Otherwise add the new keyword.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Data.DataSet.cs(158,31,158,48): warning CS0109: The member 'DataSet.Rounding.java_class_handle' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Data.DataSet.cs(159,31,159,40): warning CS0109: The member 'DataSet.Rounding.class_ref' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Data.Filter.Approximator.cs(137,30,137,47): warning CS0109: The member 'Approximator.java_class_handle' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Data.Filter.Approximator.cs(138,30,138,39): warning CS0109: The member 'Approximator.class_ref' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Data.Filter.Approximator.cs(15,31,15,48): warning CS0109: The member 'Approximator.Line.java_class_handle' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Data.Filter.Approximator.cs(16,31,16,40): warning CS0109: The member 'Approximator.Line.class_ref' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Renderer.LineChartRenderer.cs(199,31,199,48): warning CS0109: The member 'LineChartRenderer.DataSetImageCache.java_class_handle' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Charts.ScatterChart.cs(106,31,106,48): warning CS0109: The member 'ScatterChart.ScatterShape.java_class_handle' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Charts.ScatterChart.cs(107,31,107,40): warning CS0109: The member 'ScatterChart.ScatterShape.class_ref' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.
1>C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\obj\Debug\generated\src\MikePhil.Charting.Renderer.Renderer.cs(34,30,34,47): warning CS0109: The member 'Renderer.java_class_handle' does not hide an accessible member. The new keyword is not required.

   C:\Users\xamarinuser\libraries\MPAndroidChart.Xamarin\bin\Debug\MPAndroidChart.dll
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

To reiterate my issue, Is that I cannot reference a new drawable shape or image in the project because of the android binded library.

Can somebody kindly help me to fix what i need?

**UPDATE**

It seems I have similar issues with these links post [APT0000-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30934970/xamarin-forms-error-apt0000-error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-fou?noredirect=1&lq=1)

and here [NO resource found xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40425503/setup-xamarin-forms-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name)

Comment: have you tried clean and rebuild?

Comment: yes, I also restarted my machine a few times.

Comment: Have you try using the `MPAndroidChart` nuget package ?

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT Ah sadly no, there was a feature there that is not yet merged to master which is the barchart with radius. So for now I needed to finish all the charts in my app.